# Text form sends data prematurely

Tags: reactjs, forms, firebase

I’m working on creating rooms in a react chat app and I can’t seem to get my text form and submit button working properly. Anytime I enter a single keystroke two items are listed in my firebase database. The text field doesn’t even display the letter I pressed, and I don’t need to press the “Create Room” button. I’m using `event.preventDefault();` on both items but no luck.

What am I missing?

Below is the code for my chat room component. Thank you.

```
class RoomList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        rooms: [],
        newRoomName: '',
    };

    this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref('rooms');
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.newRoom = this.newRoom.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.roomsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
        const room = snapshot.val();
        room.key = snapshot.key;
        this.setState({ rooms: this.state.rooms.concat(room) });
    });
}

onChange(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    this.roomsRef.push({name: this.state.newRoomName});

}

newRoom(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({newRoomName: ''});
}


render() {
    return (
        <div className="roomlist">
            <div>
                {this.state.rooms.map((room) => <ul key={room.key}>{room.name}</ul>)}
            </div>
        <form className="submit" onChange={this.onChange}>
            <button type="submit">
                Create Room
            </button>
            <input type = "text" placeholder="New Room" value={this.state.newRoomName}  onChange={ this.onChange }/>
        </form>
        </div>


    );
}
```

}

export default RoomList;

Answer (score 0):

Many issues with your code.Will highlight a few.
You are using this.state.newRoomName for the input field value 
but in your onChange you are setting the 'text' key in setState?

```
<input type = "text" placeholder="New Room" value={this.state.newRoomName}  onChange={ this.onChange }/>

this.setState({text: event.target.value}); <-----
```

Change to

```
this.setState({newRoomName: event.target.value});
```

Second, in your onChange you are using the new value of newRoomName from the state which was just set.
setState is async so the new value might not be set at the time you do the push.
Better to use the value from the event

Third, your form submit is calling the same onChange function used for the field input?

Comment: Obviously I'm a newb. Please excuse the messy code.Thank you for the reply. 

So with the `setState` in `onChange()` it is basically offsetting the new value being pushed by the user's input in the text form. So it will always return the empty value set in `this.state`. 

Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Not offsetting - Its setting a state key that doesn't exit/not used which is why newRoomName will never get the new value

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. Thank you again.